# Return results of Django Query as Dictionary

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.TextField()
    date_time_period_start = models.DateField()
    date_time_period_end = models.DateField()
    total_sales = models.IntegerField()
```

The underlying table looks like this:

```
customer_id | date_time_period_start | date_time_period_end | total_sales
1           | 2023-04-01             | 2023-04-01           | 10
1           | 2023-04-02             | 2023-04-02           | 20
1           | 2023-04-03             | 2023-04-03           | 30
```

I would like to query using Django and return a python dictionary where the key is the value of `date_time_period_start` and the values is a dictionary where the keys are the columns and the values are the column values. In this example, I would like to return

```
{
    '2023-04-01': {'date_time_period_start': '2023-04-01', 'date_time_period_end': '2023-04-01', 'customer_id': 1, 'total_sales': 10},
    '2023-04-02': {'date_time_period_start': '2023-04-02', 'date_time_period_end': '2023-04-02', 'customer_id': 1, 'total_sales': 20},
    '2023-04-03': {'date_time_period_start': '2023-04-03', 'date_time_period_end': '2023-04-03', 'customer_id': 1, 'total_sales': 30},
}
```

I can achieve this by doing the following

```
        records = list(
            self.model.objects
            .values(
                "customer_id",
                "date_time_period_start",
                "date_time_period_end",
                "total_sales",
            )
        )
      
        records_dict = {}
        for record in records:
            records_dict[record["date_time_period_start"]] = {
                "date_time_period_start": record["date_time_period_start"],
                "date_time_period_end": record["date_time_period_end"],
                "customer_id": record["customer_id"],
                "total_sales": record["total_sales"],
            }
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this rather than looping through the list of records?

I was trying to use `values()` and `annotate()` so something like

```
from django.db.models import F

result = self.model.objects.values('date_time_period_start').annotate(date_time_period_end=F('date_time_period_end'),
    total_sales=F('total_sales'),
    customer_id=F('customer_id'),
)
```

but that gave this

```
<QuerySet [{'date_time_period_start': datetime.date(2023, 4, 1), 'date_time_period_end': datetime.date(2023, 4, 1), 'total_sales': 10, 'customer_id': 1}, {'date_time_period_start': datetime.date(2023, 4, 2), 'date_time_period_end': datetime.date(2023, 4, 2), 'total_sales': 20, 'customer_id': 1}, {'date_time_period_start': datetime.date(2023, 4, 3), 'date_time_period_end': datetime.date(2023, 4, 3), 'total_sales': 30, 'customer_id': 1}, ]>}
```

Comment: i believe there isn't a more efficient way to construct the dictionary than to loop through all elements. could you explain what your use case for this is? i believe a dictionary here isn't the best because you lose information when there are two rows with the same start date.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using Django `values` method to return a QuerySet with dictionaries, then you can use Pythons's `groupby` method to group the dictionaries.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

users = Users.objects.values(
    'date_time_period_start', 'date_time_period_end', 'custo,er_id', 'total_sales'
).order_By('date_time_period_start')

result = {}
for key, group in groupby(users, key=itemgetter('date_time_period_start')):
    result[key] = {k: v for d in group for k, v in d.items()}

print(result)
```